# Why can't I add criteria to a collection?

Tags: plone

I have added a Collection but when I click on the criteria tab and choose ANY fields such as Item Type or Location, then press the "add criteria" button, it show an error: "Criterion of type ${type} not added, it does not work with index Type."

Also the criteria type box is showing  choice code as one line in a select box... any ideas on what could cause this?

(plone 3.3.1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known bug in Plone 3.3.1, see http://dev.plone.org/plone/ticket/9522.

The fix is to upgrade to Plone 3.3.6, the latest release in the 3.3 feature line.